# Adding listener causes crash?

Tags: java, android

I have a listener interface:

```
public interface AnimationListener 
{
    public void onAnimationStarted(Animation animation);
    public void onAnimationFinished(Animation animation);
    public void onAnimationCanceled(Animation animation);
}
```

This class keeps a list:

```
public class AnimationManager 
{
    private List<Animation> animations;
    private List<AnimationListener> animationListeners;
    private List<Animation> animationsToRemove;
    private float rate;

    public AnimationManager(float rate)
    {
        setRate(rate);
    }

    public void addAnimationListener(AnimationListener listener)
    {
        animationListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeAnimationListener(AnimationListener listener)
    {
        animationListeners.remove(listener);
    }
...
```

This class implements the interface:

public class PuzzleView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, AnimationListener
{
...
    private AnimationManager animationManager = null;

```
...

public PuzzleView(Context context) 
{
            ...
    animationManager = new AnimationManager(FRAME_RATE);
    //animationManager.addAnimationListener(this); THIS CRASHES
}
```

When I add the animation listener, it crashes. What could be wrong?

Thanks

> 09-21 19:15:51.433: D/AndroidRuntime(278): Shutting down VM 09-21
>   19:15:51.433: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 09-21 19:15:51.453:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-21 19:15:51.453:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity ComponentInfo{com.joshl.drop7/com.joshl.drop7.Game}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-21 19:15:51.453:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   09-21 19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   09-21 19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 09-21
>   19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   09-21 19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-21
>   19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-21 19:15:51.453:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 09-21
>   19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-21
>   19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 09-21 19:15:51.453:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   09-21 19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 09-21
>   19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-21 19:15:51.453:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 09-21
>   19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at
>   com.joshl.drop7.AnimationManager.addAnimationListener(AnimationManager.java:19)
>   09-21 19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   com.joshl.drop7.PuzzleView.(PuzzleView.java:82) 09-21
>   19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at
>   com.joshl.drop7.Game.onCreate(Game.java:18) 09-21 19:15:51.453:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   09-21 19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   09-21 19:15:51.453: E/AndroidRuntime(278):    ... 11 more 09-21
>   19:15:53.333: I/Process(278): Sending signal. PID: 278 SIG: 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you never initialize any of the Lists in your AnimationManager class.  You should add something like this for each of your lists in your AnimationManager constructor:

```
animationListeners = new ArrayList<AnimationListener>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
public class PuzzleView implements AnimationListener {
....
public PuzzleView(Context context) 
{
            ...
    animationManager = new AnimationManager(FRAME_RATE);
    animationManager.addAnimationListener(this); 
}
.....
```

OR

```
public PuzzleView(Context context) 
{
            ...
    animationManager = new AnimationManager(FRAME_RATE);
    animationManager.addAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    }); 
}
```